# Local Search Heuristic vba compile error

Tags: vba, heuristics

Hi I am building a local search heuristic for a TSP similar problem and have encountered some bugs. I am using the sequence obtained from using the constructive heuristic (solConstr) and when I run the code there is a constant "compile error: for without next" and a highlight on the "End Sub". Please can anyone help me find the bug, thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
For b = 1 To Count
    For pos = b + 1 To Count
        changePosition = solConstr.Sequence(b)

        For c = 1 To Count
            If c >= 1 And c <= b - 1 Then
                solTemp.Sequence(c) = solConstr.Sequence(c)
            ElseIf c >= b And c <= pos - 1 Then
                solTemp.Sequence(c) = solConstr.Sequence(c + 1)
            ElseIf c >= pos + 1 And c <= Count Then
                solTemp.Sequence(c) = solConstr.Sequence(c)
            End If

            solTemp.Sequence(pos) = changePosition

            Call EvaluateSolution(shoppingInfo, solTemp)
            currentCost = solTemp.Cost
            MsgBox ("change" & b & "to" & pos & "will incur updated cost of" & currentCost)

            If currentCost < newcost Then newcost = currentCost

            For d = 1 To Count
                solTemp.Sequence(d) = solLS.Sequence(d)
            Next

        Next
    Next
Next
```

Here is the psuedo code:

Data: n, c[ij ], sol [i ], sNew[i ], i = 0, . . . , n − 1

Result: newCost

currentCost=ComputeCost(n, c[ij ], sol [i ], i = 0, . . . , n − 1);

for k = 0 To n − 1 do

for pos = 0 To n − 1, pos 6= i do

cost= EvaluateSol(n, c[ij ], sol [i ], i = 0, . . . , n − 1, k, pos);

if cost < currentCost then

currentCost = cost;

Update sNew[i ], i = 0, . . . , n − 1;

Return sNew;

end

end

end